# Pinescript How to display strategy.account_currency?

Tags: pine-script

```
var table theTable = table.new(bottom_right, 1, 5)
if true
    table.cell(theTable, 0, 0, strategy.account_currency)
```

The code above is supposed to display the account currency used by the strategy. When I run it, it just displays a blank table. Am I doing something wrong? How do I display `strategy.account_currency`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = na(strategy.account_currency)?syminfo.currency:strategy.account_currency)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get why it's not displaying properly.